# PagingMemoryProxy in extjs grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to use pagingmemoryproxy in my grid to search data in grid. What are the requirements to use pagingmemoryproxy from remotedata. can anyboby help me please.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example for u:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?192410-LocalPagingProxy-an-alternative-to-PagingMemoryProxy

or follow this:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/12/extjs-pagingmemoryproxy-ajax-json-data.html